# Writing a newline in a file in a Runnable thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, printwriter

I would like to write a simple class to print to a file every 5 seconds.

My code is:

```
public class FileLoggerTask implements Runnable
{
    private PrintWriter printWriter = null;
    private boolean isActive = true;

    public FileLoggerTask(PrintWriter printWriter)
    {
        this.printWriter = printWriter;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(isActive)
        {
            printWriter.println("Test line");

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }

            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    void closeTask()
    {
        isActive = false;
    }
}
```

And in the listener of one button I write:

```
File file = new File("TestFile.txt");
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
FileLoggerTask fileLoggerTask = new FileLoggerTask(printWriter);
Thread thread = new Thread(fileLoggerTask);
```

and in the listener of another button I write:

```
fileLoggerTask.closeTask();
printWriter.close();
```

My problem is that it writes "Test line" in my file every 5 seconds but it doesn't append any newline. I have tried adding printWriter.println() or printWriter.println("\n") but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Do you have some suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: FYI: `isActive` probably should be `volatile`.

Comment: What gets written to the file?  Just multiple `Test line`s with no newline?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly: You get several `Test line` but all of them are in a single line; there is no space between them?

Comment: Yes, it writes "Test lineTest lineTest lineTest line" and so on...
Right, it's all on a single line.

Comment: If you are on unix, can you pass the file through `od -c file` or some other hex-dump utility to see the actual bytes in the file?  As others have recommended, maybe your file editor is hiding the newlines?   Maybe use this online tool: http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm

Comment: I am not on unix so i can't try your test... I should probably say I am running my program in an Android emulator, but I think it doesn't matter much...

Comment: @JohnQ That can make a difference. I just tried the above code on Win7 and it prints the lines just fine.

Comment: And how are you viewing the output file?  Are you getting it from the SD card under windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you know there is no newline? I'm asking because if you are using some text editor on windows but your code is running on Unix, you might not see them.

Have you tried `printWriter.println("\n\r")` ?

Comment: +1 He tried `printWriter.println("\n")` and that didn't give him a new line, either. Must be a problem in the tool that he uses to display the data.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I have tried to write printWriter.println("\n\r") and it works.
Do you have an idea of what's happening?

Comment: @JohnQ You are generating the file on an architecture (Android) that has a different line terminator than the system you are viewing on (most likely Windows).

Comment: Btw @JohnQ, typically you print "\r\n" instead of the other way around.

Comment: unix (and therefor android) use \n as end of line. windows expects a couple \r\n. the newlines are here, but your windows doesn't consider them.

Comment: @mprivat Seriously? I've had this issue before and that never, ever would have occured to me! Thanks a million for that, it's been a big help on something I'm currently working on!

Comment: All this being said though, if you are planning on re-reading your files from your app, using \r\n (Thanks @JohnQ) might cause side effects. I'm not a Windows user, but I think Notepad++ lets you see the proper carriage returns. If you're just outputting debug logs, you're probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Comment: How does that help?  `println` does the right thing there.  Are you implying that the system line separator is incorrect?